# PHP fgetcsv error - How can I arrange it?

Tags: php

I am getting the following error:

"Notice: fgetcsv() [function.fgetcsv]: delimiter must be a single character" in my browser

My PHP Code is as follows -  can someone rearrange it please?

```
$fh = fopen('notes.txt', 'r') or die('Unable to open notes.txt');
while(($line = fgetcsv($fh, 0, '||')) !== FALSE)
   if ($line[0] == $name) {
       echo <<<EOL

My color is $line[2]
EOL;
       break; // if there's only ever one '5678' line in the, get out now.
   }

fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Not without seeing the data and what you're trying to do.

Comment: "delimiter must be a single character" -- what cannot you get in this phrase?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: it's not about data, it's about 3rd `fgetcsv` parameter

Comment: It's ***ALWAYS*** about the data.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: no, it's about 3rd parameter

Answer (score 1):

from the [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) documentation, your delimiter can only be one character in length. for future reference though when asking a question to do with files being able to see the data (or a sample of data) is invaluable

Answer (score 0):

In simple words you are using tow characers "||" when you can only one like comma ",". [Read the documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: I used your solution but now I am getting this error - 'Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in'. How can I solve it now?